# Organized list with border

Tags: lists

I saw this list type in a Latex generated document, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what the syntax for it is supposed to be.

Here's an image of the list in question:

[image]

I know this is probably not the best formulated question, but I've exhausted all of LaTeX resources and I don't know where to turn.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

It’s a table, using the [`tabular` environment](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables). The left column is right-aligned and the right column is left-aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\arrayrulecolor[gray]{0.7}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r|l}
2012 - Nu & IT \\
2009 - 2012 & Net \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}{r|l}
\textbf{Dansk} & \textbf{Fly} \\
Engelsk & Fly \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]